# Benchmarking Native Android Apps

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I wish to perform some benchmarking on a native android app I'm currently working with. I've managed to print some desired data to logcat in eclipse but I am looking for a good way of 1) running the tests multiple times and 2) recording the logcat output.

I'm normally a c++ developer so I'm much more familiar with say, running a bash script in terminal to execute a program multiple times and redirecting the output to a text file. However, I'm not sure if I can do something similar for a native android app.

Any advice on a place to start would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, while there are frameworks for this kind of thing, if bash scripting is the environment you like, there's no reason you can't use it.

- You can launch activities with the adb shell and the `am start` command, for example

  adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n your.package.name/.YourActivity'
- `adb logcat` happily outputs to stdout on the host, where you can readily grep for whatever is of interest or do any other analysis you desire

Comment: But when I do am start, it returns right after starting the activity, so how can I know when the app has finished?

Comment: Watch logcat.  Android apps run in their own process regardless (which tends to hang around for possible re-use), so any serialization of execution will only happen by messaging/monitoring.